# Add div to another div, then make some actions and then remove added div. How?

Tags: jquery

```
$div = $('<div>Here is my div!</div>');
$('#bar').append($div.html());
//do some actions
$div.remove();
```

But appended div isn't removed?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You're cloning HTML

You have to omit `.html()` call because you're cloning the `$div` HTML.

```
// always use a "var" in front of non-global variables
var div = $("<div>Here is my div!</div>");

// just add your jQuery element here. No call to .html()
$("#bar").append(div);

//do some actions

div.remove();
```

But I hope that the *do some actions* is a lengthy operation in terms of time or user interaction otherwise I don't know what this functionality is for (creating, adding, doing some mangling and removing).

Comment: @Blankasaurus: Yes it was confusing because I can't see whether a jQuery function is used or is it something else... Mind the local variable declaration in the first line as well. :)

Comment: I prefer to mark jQuery object variable with $ - it usually helps me a lot, really. I can't see any evil doing this.

Comment: @Kirzilla: Do whatever pleases you as long as it doesn't break the code. I removed those $ fore readability purposes. But your naming convention does make sense although many would probably complain about it.